# add to an array dynamically

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

```
//getting values from dataBase
$sql = "SELECT  `email` ,  `password` FROM  `user_inf`";
// Execute query
$result = mysql_query($sql,$con);
$email;
$pass;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$email = $row['email'];
$pass  = $row['password'];
}



// create a dummy array
$doc = array (
1 => array ("Email", "Password")
     array ($email, $pass),
);
```

I need to fill that array "doc"   dynamically .The value I am getting from database and fetching using that while loop.I want to put all those value in that array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do it like this:

```
$result = mysql_query( "SELECT  `email` ,  `password` FROM  `user_inf`", $con );
$doc = array( array( "Email", "Password" ) );
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ) {
    $doc[] = array( $row['email'], $row['password'] );
}
```

Comment: Thanks Eugene Manuilov Thanks a lot.Why some one down voted you your ans in correct